# Kerberos service authentication

Tags: kerberos, cloudera

I have installed Kerberos on my Cloudera manager server and I want to control which components each user can use through Kerberos. Currently, once you create a principal for the user, he immediately can use every service/component.

So is it possible to control which services (Impala, hive, etc.) a user can use through Kerberos? Or not?

Comment: Generally speaking, no. Once the core Hadoop components (HDFS, YARN) are kerberized, all other client-facing services **must** use Kerberos auth (internally) to run. And clients are expected to use STRONG authentication to access the services, which then impersonate them against Hadoop core services.

Comment: But some services act as **auth gateways** e.g. LDAP on the outside, Kerberos on the inside => Impala, HiveServer2, and of course **Knox**.